# Proving $\frac{\sin 2x - \cos x}{4\sin^2x -1} = \frac{\sin^2x+\cos x+\cos^2x}{2\sin x +1} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to prove that this is an identity:

> $$\frac{\sin 2x - \cos x}{4\sin^2x -1} = \frac{\sin^2x+\cos x+\cos^2x}{2\sin x +1} $$

Here's what I'm confused on:

- I noticed that the expression in the denominator for the first expression ($4sin^2(x) -1)$ looks like a *double angle identity*, but it also looks like a *difference of squares*. **I know I can solve this as a difference of squares.** Am I correct that this is a double angle identity, and if so, how can I solve it?
- I could rearrange the numerator for the second expression ($\sin^2x+\cos x+\cos^2x$) to sub in $1$ for $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta$ (**Pythagorean identity**, where  $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$)
  By doing so, I'd get $\cos x + 1$. But, this must be incorrect, for the final answer is $\dfrac{\cos x}{2\sin x-1} = \dfrac{\cos x}{2\sin x-1}$. **That means the cosine must've been multiplied by $1$.** How is that so?

*(Here's the picture of the problem)*
[image: picture of the problem]

Comment: Are you sure you recorded the problem correctly?

Comment: @Bladewood I copied this problem off from an illegible picture of math notes my friend has sent me. If it helps I can attach that photo to this problem.

Comment: Okay, that changes things. This looks like a completely different problem to me: the numerator of the RHS is $\sin^2 x \cos x + \cos^3 x$, which the second line follows by factoring out $\cos x$ (although I'm not sure how the rest of it follows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin(2x)=2\sin (x)\cos (x)$. Therefore you are *solving*:
$$\frac{\cos (x)}{2\sin(x)+1}=\frac{\cos(x)+1}{2\sin(x)+1}$$
Which leads to the nonsense equation:
$$\cos(x)=\cos(x)+1$$ which certainly has no solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot prove it because it is false:

$$\frac{\sin(2x) - \cos x}{4\sin^2(x) -1 }= \frac{2\sin x\cos x - \cos x}{(2\sin x -1)(2\sin x +1)} = \frac{\cos x}{2\sin x +1} \color{red}{\neq} \frac{1+\cos x}{2\sin x +1}$$

Answer (score 3):

When $x=0$ the left side equals 1 and the right side equals 2, so it is not an identity.

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out, the equation is not an identity. To directly address your confusions, $4\sin^2(x)-1$ is similar to the double-angle identity $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$, from which we can derive the identity $4\sin^2(x)-1=-2\cos(2x)+1$. However, it doesn't seem using this substitution helps, and only complicates it by changing the easier to deal with $\sin^2(x)$ term into the more difficult $\cos(2x)$. Since the equation is not a identity, $\dfrac{\cos x}{2\sin x-1} = \dfrac{\cos x}{2\sin x-1}$ does not follow from the equation. The Pythagorean identity is actually the correct substitution to make. Your friend has made a mistake in the RHS in the second line, incorrectly factoring $\sin^2(x)+\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)$ into $(\cos x)(\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)$.

Comment: ¿Que?  There are definitely no solutions as they require $\cos(x)=\cos(x)+1$

Comment: Never mind, forgot to check for extraneous solutions.